# How to tweak tp4056 module to run on 8v?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion

I have a tp4056 module:[image: module]

How can I tweak it to run on 4v to 8v range (it's maximum voltage rating according to the datasheet).
[datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)

Comment: Add LDO regulator on front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the current set resistor (connected to pin 2 of the IC, marked "122" in the picture, 1200 Ohms) in order to lower the charging current to a value that won't cause excessive power dissipation in the IC. 250mA should be safe, which means that the new resistor should have 5k Ohms according to the datasheet.

Other than that, you don't have to do anything as the chip can already handle 8V at its input.

If you want to be extra careful, you could replace the two SMD capacitors with 10µF 16V types just in case the manufacturer of the PCB used ones rated for only 6.3V.